# Create objects in worker thread and bind to them

Tags: c#, wpf, exception, binding, multithreading

I've a problem with cross-thread operations in C# / WPF / .NET 4.0.

**The situation:**

I have to create a object tree when the user clicks a button and then bind to the tree. Because the creation takes a long time (child objects are recursively instantiated), I used a Thread/BackgroundWorker/Task to prevent the UI from freezing.

**The problem:**

I get a XamlParserException (Must create DependencySource on same Thread as the DependencyObject) when binding to the object tree.

I understand the problem, but how can it be fixed? I can't create the object tree on the UI thread because this will freeze the UI. But I also can't create the object-tree on another thread because then I'm not able to bind to it.

Is there a way to 'marshal' objects to the UI thread?

**The Event Handler Code** (executed on UI thread)

```
    private void OnDiff(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        string path1 = this.Path1.Text;
        string path2 = this.Path2.Text;

        // Some simple UI updates.
        this.ProgressWindow.SetText(string.Format(
            "Comparing {0} with {1}...",
            path1, path2));

        this.IsEnabled = false;
        this.ProgressWindow.Show();
        this.ProgressWindow.Focus();

        // The object tree to be created.
        Comparison comparison = null;

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {

            // May take a few seconds...
            comparison = new Comparison(path1, path2);

        }).ContinueWith(x =>
        {


            // Again some simple UI updates.
            this.ProgressWindow.SetText("Updating user interface...");
            this.DiffView.Items.Clear();
            this.Output.Items.Clear();

            foreach (Comparison diffItem in comparison.Items)
            {
                this.DiffView.Items.Add(diffItem);

                this.AddOutput(diffItem);
            }

            this.Output.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

            this.IsEnabled = true;
            this.ProgressWindow.Hide();

        }, CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());

    }
```

**Example Binding**

```
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn CellTemplate="{StaticResource DataGridIconCellTemplate}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Status" Binding="{Binding Path=ItemStatus}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Type"   Binding="{Binding Path=ItemType}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Path"   Binding="{Binding Path=RelativePath}"
                                    Width="*"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
```

Greetings,
Dominik

Comment: It would help if you could show some of your code.

Comment: I added some code snippets to the question via Edit action.

Comment: you shouldn't add `[Solved]` to your title or post a solution in your question. You will have to wait 24 hour but you should post the solution in your own answer which you can then accept (again after a delay). This then indicates to the system and other users that the problem is solved.

Comment: @ChrisF - Sorry for the [Solved] tag. I just wanted to prevent others from putting effort into an already solved problem. I tried to solve it for about two days and found the solution just after i posted the question.

Comment: don't worry too much - and about solving just after you post, that seems to happen a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create the icon on the worker thread, but you need to freeze it before you use it on the UI thread:

```
            var icon = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHIcon(
              sysicon.Handle,
              System.Windows.Int32Rect.Empty,
              System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
            icon.Freeze();
            Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => this.Icon = icon));
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you used the Dispatcher.Invoke method before? My understanding is you can have a long running process executing on a separate thread (eg Task) and use the Dispatcher to update the controls on the UI thread using a delegate.

```
private void DoWork()
{
    // Executed on a separate thread via Thread/BackgroundWorker/Task

    // Dispatcher.Invoke executes the delegate on the UI thread
    Dispatcher.Invoke(new System.Action(() => SetDatesource(myDatasource)));
}
```